# Packages cannot locate QT5 (BLFS 8.4)

Tags: lfs

I'm trying to install BLFS 8.4
I've installed QT5 but somehow other packages that need QT5 cannot find it.

E.g. while installing highlight, after the command `make gui`, it says `qmake command not found`.
Similarly 'extra-cmake-modules-5.55.0' and 'oxygen-icons5-5.55.0' couldn't find "qcollectiongenerator, linguist, qcore, etc."

These packages are present in `/opt/qt-5.12.1/bin`.
Which command shows output:

```
which qmake-qt5
/usr/bin/qmake-qt5
```

I installed QT5 in /opt directory.

Comment: `ls -l $(which qmake-qt5)` or `readlink $(which qmake-qt5)`

Comment: What will it do (the second one)? Where should I implement this?

Comment: ```sudo ln -s `which qmake-qt5` /usr/bin/qmake``` I tried to use this.

Comment: No, you just need to run the commands, one or the other, to see that `/usr/bin/qmake-qt5` is a symlink to `/opt/qt.../qmake`. ... and don't go `sudo`-ing anything that you don't understand.

Comment: @rfmodulator although I installed it in `/opt/q...` and symlinked `which qmake-qt5`  to `/usr/bin/qmake`, it's working fine! Should I create another symlink for `/opt/q...` directory?

Comment: The `(B)LFS` way is to configure it by the book, see my answer below... of course, you may do whatever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely need to complete the section on "Configration Qt5", specifically where it says "If you installed Qt5 in a location other than /usr, you need to..."

After this is done, and you login, `echo $QT5DIR` should output `/opt/qt5`.

This also ensures that `/opt/qt5/bin` is in $PATH and that `ldconfig` finds the qt5 libraries.

This is very important, because a lot of stuff depends on `Qt`...

First, lets ensure that the symlink in `/opt` and the environment variable is correct, as *root*:

```
# readlink $QT5DIR
qt-5.15.0
# ls $QT5DIR
bin  doc  include  lib  mkspecs  phrasebooks  plugins  qml  translations
```

(Your output may be a little different, but both commands should output *something* other than an error.)

Now, configure Qt5 as the book describes (again, installed in `/opt` instead of `/usr`), as *root*:

```
cat >> /etc/ld.so.conf << EOF
# Begin Qt addition

/opt/qt5/lib

# End Qt addition
EOF
```

Then, as *root*:

```
ldconfig
```

And finally, as *root*:

```
cat > /etc/profile.d/qt5.sh << "EOF"
# Begin /etc/profile.d/qt5.sh

QT5DIR=/opt/qt5

pathappend $QT5DIR/bin           PATH
pathappend $QT5DIR/lib/pkgconfig PKG_CONFIG_PATH

export QT5DIR

# End /etc/profile.d/qt5.sh
EOF
```

At this point, if you logout and login, `echo $PATH` will contain `/opt/qt5/bin`.

Now, you need to undo all of the weird stuff that you did while trying to troubleshoot your issue. (i.e. if you created a symlink `/usr/bin/qmake`, delete it, etc.)

Comment: I had already checked for this. It was giving correct output.

Comment: No, it wasn't, because if `/opt/qt5/bin` were in your path, then `qmake` would have been found without creating a symlink in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: `echo $PATH` gives `/bin:/usr/bin` and `echo $QT5DIR` gives `/opt/qt5`

Comment: Exactly, you need to complete "Configuring Qt5"

Comment: What should be the output then?

Comment: I checked for the CAT files, they are present.

Comment: Please read and follow my edits above carefully.

Comment: After I did the configuration again as you said, everything worked correctly, the echo outputs and even the previous packages that couldn't find QT! Although I'm sure that `echo PATH` gave `/opt/qt5/bin` when I first made qt but the output was different today after shutdown of my laptop!

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link https://www.blogetcetera.com/2017/qmake-command-not-found/

You just have to create a symlink.
`` sudo ln -s `which qmake-qt5` /usr/bin/qmake ``
Make sure that 'qmake-qt5' is present.
Which command gives output:

```
which qmake-qt5
/usr/bin/qmake-qt5
```

Comment: While this might solve your current problem, you will likely have more problems in the future because your environment is not correctly setup for `BLFS`.